# How to set UIImageView animation in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview, endpoint

Now i am working in iPhone application, Using UIImageView to create a animation and it's working fine, then i tried to call one method for when the animation once completed then the button to show on the screen, but that button showing first then the animation starts, i want once animation completed then the button showing on the screen, how to fix this issue? please help me

Thanks in Advance

I tried this for your reference:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        NSArray * imageArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardopen.png"], 
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"middlecard.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"thirdcard.png"], 
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"],

                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"cardopen1.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"middlecard2.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"thirdcard1.png"], 
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],

                                         nil];

         UIImageView * cardsImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 400, 300)];
            cardsImage.animationImages = imageArray;
            cardsImage.animationDuration = 8.0;
            cardsImage.animationRepeatCount=1; // one time looping only
            [self.view addSubview:cardsImage];
            [cardsImage startAnimating];  

             [self method1]; // To Call a method1 to show UIButton (Once the animation is completed, then to call a method1)

    }

    -(void)method1
    {
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.frame=CGRectMake(10, 40, 50, 50);
        [self.view addSubview:btn];
    }
```

Comment: use the nstimer in start the animation.

Comment: rum your method1 after delay of 8 sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Why doesn't anybody understand the concept of asynchronous methods? Is this *that hard*?)

```
[cardsImage startAnimating];
```

returns immediately, not after the animation finished. You have to set an explicit timeout:

```
NSTimer *tm = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInteral:imageView.animationDuration * imageView.animationCount // assuming animationCount is not 0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(method1)
    repeats:NO
    userInfo:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use
 `[self performSelector:@selector(method1) withObject:nil afterDelay:8.0];`

instead of `[self method1];`

Comment: my concept is same as H2CO3...according to H2CO3's answer you have to declare imageView in .h file, and according to my code no need of this....

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are putting all of your code in `ViewDidLoad`. The whole method will be processed . Plus you have your **animation duration** set to 0.8 which is a slow animation.So the button would appear normally and the animation would continue along with it and then even more. So what you actually have to do is use an `NSTimer` or use the answers provided to you here :)